# There's no better way to Count Keys In Cassandra？

Tags: cassandra

I have a log table in cassandra, and now I want to search the rows count of the table.

First, I use the `select count(*) from log`,but it's very, very slow.
Then I want to use the `counter` type, and then the problem is coming. My table is a TTL table, all rows keep an hour, use the `counter` type become very difficult.

Comment: you can try count(*) from log with limit clause,it will be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra isn't efficient for doing table scan operations.  It is good at ingesting high volumes of data and then accessing small slices of that data rather than the whole table.

So if you want to count keys without using a counter, you need to break the table into chunks of data that are small enough to be processed quickly.  For example if you want to use count(*), you should only use it on a single partition, and keep the partition size below about 100,000 rows.

In your case you might want to partition your data by hour (or something small like 5 minute intervals if you insert a lot of log lines per second).

Be careful with using a TTL of an hour if you are inserting a lot of data continuously since it could cause a lot of tombstones.  To avoid building up tombstones you should delete each hour partition after the hour has passed.